# why <li> tags are not inline on my slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a fluid slider width:100%
it works perfectly until I add more than 4 items. After 4 items the 5 item goes under the 1 item.

this how `<li>` should look like inline

```
12345678
```

but instead they go under like this

```
1234
5678
```

I know it has to be something with the width but when I add more width to the parent the items go off place
heres a js fiddle i made . please help!

https://jsfiddle.net/jaysg_/tk20dckv/light/

Comment: You have them set to `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way youre setting your widths. You have 8 slides so you have to do the math:

100 / 8 = 12.5

That means that each slide should have a width of 12.5% and your slide container should have a width of 800%:

Try this:

```
.work-slider ul {
    width: 800%;
}
.work-slider ul li {
    width: 12.5%;
}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tk20dckv/7/**

Comment: wow I can't believe I miss that. I knew i had to make it 800% but totally missed that math

Comment: It happens, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

If the ul tag has `width:100px;` and every li tag has `width:50px;` you will see 12, 34, 56... can you imagine why??